# What does means .body tag in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

what does mean this part of code in css file

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #portfolio-list li .header {
      display: block;
```

or

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #portfolio-list li .body {
      display: block;
```

what means .body or .header in this code?

Comment: they are class names - elements whose class attribute is (or contain) either `body` or `header`

Answer (score 2):

To break down the rule(s) in full:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
```

This is a width based [**Media Query**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#width) and is effectively saying when the width of the viewport is above `992px` then apply the following rule:

```
#portfolio-list li .header {
```

This is a CSS rule made up of a series of [**selectors**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html).

- `#` designates an element's `id` attribute, so select the element with the id `portfolio-list`
- `li` is an element type (list item), so select all list items within `#portfolio-list`
- `.header` matches all elements with the `header` class within list items within `#portfolio-list`

So all elements with the `header` class within list items `li` within the element with the `id` attribute `portfolio-list`

Example markup the above would select based upon could be e.g:

```
<div id="portfolio-list"> <!-- in your CSS: #portfolio-list -->
 <ul>
  <li> <!-- in your CSS: li -->
    <span class="header">THIS</span> <!-- in your CSS: .header -->
    <span>(not this)</span>
  </li>
 </ul>
<div>
```

The space after each selector denotes the next should relate to child elements.

As mentioned elsewhere, a period/fullstop/dot prefix `.` in a CSS rule denotes a class selector. As such, `.body` and `.header` relate to CSS classes, and should not be confused with the `<body>` or `<header>` elements, which would simply be selected using element selectors: `body` or `header`

Comment: So i therefor you mean that .body or .header just a class? and no relative to <body> or <header> element?
it doesn't against the syntax rule of CSS?

Comment: Why should it? body and header aren't reserved words in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You use body and header in your html, to style them in css you use:

```
.body { 
    styling code like background;
}

.header {
    code;
}
```

Comment: But this is pretty much what Fabrizio caldaran just sad.